# What is the default value of 'scope' attribute in JSTL tags?

Tags: jsp, scope, jstl

It is not defined in [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) neither for `<fmt:message>` nor for `<c:url>` tags.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

From [JSTL specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jstl-1.1-mr2-spec-oth-JSpec/jstl-1_1-mr2-spec.pdf) (emphasis mine):

> ## 2.2.1 var and scope
>
> ...
>
> The `scope` attribute has the semantics defined in the JSP specification, and takes the
>   same values as the ones allowed in the <jsp:useBean> action; i.e. `page`, `request`,
>   `session`, `application`. **If no value is specified for `scope`, `page` scope is the
>   default unless otherwise specified**.
>
> ...

In other words, the default is `page`, i.e. the current JSP page.

The same applies to `<c:set>`, by the way.